# Elegantly Solving Setting a Value When Only Some Methods Need the Range Variable

Tags: c#, oop

I have a method (stripped for readability) that takes a func:

```
private TestEntityContainer CreateTestEntityContainer(string rootName,
        Func<InstallationSummary, DateTime> forceInstallationTimeFunc,
        bool forceInstallEnvironmentShouldMatch, bool freezeAllInstallations, int numberOfInstallationSummariesToCreate)
{   
    // Other code exists above here. Note that we use two variables, appServer and appWithGroup,
    // created earlier in this method, here:
    var mostRecentInstallationSummary = InstallationSummaryLogic.GetMostRecentByServerAppAndGroup(appServer, appWithGroup);

    var forceInstallation = new ForceInstallation();
    // This is where the func is invoked. We need other things, created above, for this to work.
    forceInstallation.ForceInstallationTime = forceInstallationTimeFunc.Invoke(mostRecentInstallationSummary);
    // Do more things with forceInstallation here
}
```

Here are two sample callers, one that uses the range variable:

```
var container = CreateTestEntityContainer("UseCase12", x => x.InstallationStart.AddSeconds(1), true, false, 5);
```

And one that doesn't:

```
var container = CreateTestEntityContainer("UseCase10", x => DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), false, false, 0);
```

That seems like a hack. Is there a better way to solve this where consumers don't need to use a func that's unnecessary in many cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your problem, I would suggest using method overloading here, rather then trying to craft some nifty way of getting one method signature to suit all consumers.

Comment: You're right. I was trying to make one method handle everything, and it was becoming inelegant. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving the function an instance of `Foo`, you can give them a function that has the ability to create a `Foo`:

```
private TestEntityContainer CreateContainer(Func<Func<Foo>, DateTime> func) {
  Func<Foo> creator = () => new Foo();
  forceInstallation.ForceInstallationTime = func.Invoke(creator);
}
```

Now the consumer can create the `Foo` if needed:

```
var container = CreateContainer(x => x().InstallationStart.AddSeconds(1));
```

Comment: It's always necessary to create the `Foo`. It's just that setting one property on it changes.

Comment: @BobHorn: Then there isn't much of an issue. Passing along a reference to an object that already exists anyway is very little overhead. Overloading the method to take a function without a parameter would either cause repeated code, or more overhead.

Comment: I just change the question to be less abstract. Maybe it will help to understand what I'm trying.

Comment: Fixed. It was a typo from trying to make it clean and abstract for the original post.

Comment: @BobHorn: The parameters doesn't match. What is it that you are trying to clarify?

Comment: Dang it. Fixed. Sorry. I'm just trying to put the actual code there, because that may affect the answer. After seeing the actual code, does your answer still apply?

Comment: @BobHorn: Yes. If you would want to avoid to create the instance in the first place you can use the approach above, otherwise there isn't really any good reason to avoid passing the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an overload of `CreateContainer` with a Func that doesn't take a parameter? Something like:

```
private TestEntityContainer CreateContainer(Func<DateTime> func)
{   
    forceInstallation.ForceInstallationTime = func.Invoke();
}

var container = CreateContainer(() => DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
```

Comment: Hmmm... I wouldn't want to repeat the entire method because of that one line. You've given me something to think about though...

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I *do not* recommend this but It might be useful for one of those *quick and dirty* moments.

You could change your method signature and add optional parameters:

```
CreateTestEntityContainer(string s, bool forceInstallEnvironmentShouldMatch,
    bool freezeAllInstallations, int numberOfInstallationSummariesToCreate , 
    Func<InstallationSummary, DateTime> f = null)
```

And only use the function when `f != null`

You could then call it like this:

```
var firstContainer = CreateTestEntityContainer("UseCase12", true, false, 5,  x => x.InstallationStart.AddSeconds(1));
var secondContainer = CreateTestEntityContainer("UseCase10", false, false, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work for the case where I want to use a date (the func that doesn't use the range variable).